# How to export the details of a digital certificate (.cer file) to a csv file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a digital certificate that I'm using for a specific task. I need to export the details of the certificate such as the serial number and issuer to a csv file that is already on my computer using PowerShell. Please keep in mind this is a digital certificate that is not installed on my computer but was sent to me and I downloaded it.

Comment: What you've presented is a task, not a code problem. Please provide you're attempt at solving this issue, with an example of what the result should look like; properly formatted.

Comment: Also, you probably want to control your tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the certificate details using the command `Get-PfxCertificate` as follow

```
$certpath = 'D:\cert.cer'
Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certpath | Export-Csv .\cert.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate?view=powershell-5.1